# How can I convert a list of tuples to a dict with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I convert list of tuples like:

```
query_res = [('a3','b6','c1'),
             ('a3','b6','c2'),
             ('a3','b6','c3'),
             ('a3','b7','c4'),
             ('a4','b8','c5'),
             ('a4','b8','c6')]
```

to a dict like:

```
result = {
    'a3': {
        'b6': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
        'b7': ['c4']
    },
    'a4': {
        'b8': ['c5', 'c6']
    }
}
```

I have tried defaultdict, bug can only get inner dict, how can I map `a` to `res` here?:

```
res = defaultdict(list)
for a, b, c in query_res:
    res[b].append(c)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
query_res = [('a3','b6','c1'),
             ('a3','b6','c2'),
             ('a3','b6','c3'),
             ('a3','b7','c4'),
             ('a4','b8','c5'),
             ('a4','b8','c6')]

result = {}
for key, subkey, value in query_res:
    result.setdefault(key, {}).setdefault(subkey, []).append(value)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a3': 
    {'b6': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], 
     'b7': ['c4']
     },
 'a4': 
    {'b8': ['c5', 'c6']
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh, that's all I need.

Comment: Its a best way of creating dict of dict's if we need to add list in a inner dictionary. But what if we have only one value against each key in inner dictionary. Can it work for the same scenario? or we need any changes in above code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

You can nest `defaultdict`s:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for a, b, c in query_res:
    d[a][b].append(c)

pprint.pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10acb1f28>,
            {'a3': defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
                               {'b6': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
                                'b7': ['c4']}),
             'a4': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b8': ['c5', 'c6']})})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `for loop` and `if` condition.

**Ex.**

```
query_res = [('a3','b6','c1'),
             ('a3','b6','c2'),
             ('a3','b6','c3'),
             ('a3','b7','c4'),
             ('a4','b8','c5'),
             ('a4','b8','c6')]

my_dict = {}

for a,b,c in query_res:
    #append nested dictionary key value
    if a in my_dict and b in my_dict[a]:
        my_dict[a][b].append(c)
   #check nested dictionary key does not exist then add key, value
    elif a in my_dict and b not in my_dict[a]:
        my_dict[a][b] = [c]
    else:
        my_dict[a] = {}
        my_dict[a][b] = [c]

print(my_dict)
```

**O/P:**

```
{'a3': {'b6': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], 'b7': ['c4']}, 'a4': {'b8': ['c5', 'c6']}}
```